# Changing background color without affecting objects in a scene

Tags: rendering, shaders

I need to render a sort of a mask of the objects animation, where the background is solid black and the object is solid white. However when I try to change the background color, the object changes color aswell. I am setting the color in World properties -> Surface -> Color.

[image]

Is there any other option to change the background color, whilst preserving the color of the object? Or are the shading settings at fault here? Is there any way to entirely turn off the shading?

[image]

I would like this object to be completely white without any shading

Comment: Hello and welcome :). The linked thread answers only the first part. To make your object completely white and without shading, use the [Emission node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/shader/emission.html) set to 1. That way, your object won't receive any shadows.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I have overcome the issue by placing a few lights around the scene, but your solution is much cleaner.

Comment: Happy to help :). You can use standard world colors (black in your case) for the background, because there will be no shading anymore.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ consider adding as  an answer to the duplicate.

Comment: @batFINGER Isn't there a way to reopen this question instead? It's actually quite different from the "duplicate". This one is about a flat silhouette on a flat background, essentially 2D animation. Is there a way to reopen it somehow?

Comment: Vote to re-open. Editing will put it up for reopen in review.

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ or you could [wait for another question or create a new user and ask the question then answer that one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/161405/mesh-objects-take-the-color-of-world-blender-2-81a) lol.. such serendipity.