# Mesh objects take the color of World (Blender 2.81a)

Tags: rendering, world

[image]In my Blender project, there is a two-dimensional mesh object. It has the color **white**. In the "solid" view it indeed shows up white. However, when rendering a video or picture ("rendered" view), it takes the color of the "world" (which is **blue**). So it only becomes visible (in blue) when there are other objects in the background.

How can I make this object show its intended color (white) in "rendered" view (and therefore in any baked picture or video)?

PS: I have tried giving the object other colors than white, and then there is no problem. So only when it is white it takes the color of "world", whatever that color is.

PICTURE: the temple is the object. It hovers in front of the dark blue rectangle. The left picture is in "material" view, the right is in "rendered" view. In de rendered view it has somehow taken the color of the "world" (the lighter blue). So if I change the color of the world to e.g. red, then the temple turns red as well.

Comment: Hello and welcome :). Please [add an image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75498/652639) of what's going on. Without that it's just guessing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In renders, all objects reflect the *World color*.
White objects are affected most, they reflect it almost perfectly. Like in reality.

**Solution 1 - Emission node**
Use the Emission node for your object's color.
That way, the object will not receive any shadows or color tint.
It will just be a silhouette emiting white light.
Might work well for 2D animation.

*Add > Shader > Emission*

[image]

*Comparing different materials.

Even colored materials get a slight tint.*

[image]

**Solution 2 - Using the compositor**

[Available here on Blender Stack Exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/108870/78972) by the legendary [cegaton](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/1853/cegaton) himself.

Cegaton's answer offers a different approach using the compositor.
Rendered objects keep grey shading, but the background color can be changed at will.

---

Try what works best for you :).

Comment: Solution 1 worked beautifully. Made trying Solution 2 superfluous ;) Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you :). You can now mark the question as accepted **✓**, for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple node setup
[image]

Diffuse is the color, you apply it to the emission and diffuse. Mix shader fac balances the two together. Something about .35 or .4 works best. Ur welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.91, all objects take on the color of the World.  So even if I have a 1000x bright sun lamp shining on a white cube, the cube is totally black if the World background is black.  This is NOT how real lighting works.

Blender 2.79 does not have this problem, so it is a bug.

Emission makes everything glow a bit, and real things should not have to glow to be visible.

Comment: The sun lamp should work just fine, bloom is optional and has a threshold to keep glare limited to a certain brightness range.  afaik no bug like this could realistically make it into master.